# Configure a Raspbery Pi Nextcloud local server to run https with Docker containers

Tags: docker, webserver, nginx, nextcloud, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a Nextcloud server on my local nextwork using a Raspberry Pi. To do so, I used 3 docker images: nextcloud, posgresql and nginx. But even if I want to use this cloud only within my local network, I would like to configure Nextcloud to work via https to be more secure. So far I've try many things but nothing works. Here's my docker-compose.yml file and the nginx.conf file that I have.

Can you help me?

Docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nextcloud:
    image: nextcloud
    container_name: nextcloud
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=db
      - POSTGRES_DB=nextcloud
      - POSTGRES_USER=nextcloud
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - /MyCloud/nextcloud:/var/www/html
      - /MyCloud/data:/var/www/html/data
      - /MyCloud/apps:/var/www/html/custom_apps
      - /MyCloud/config:/var/www/html/config
      - /MyCloud/themes:/var/www/html/themes
    networks:
      - nextcloud-net
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=nextcloud
      - POSTGRES_USER=nextcloud
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
    volumes:
      - /db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - nextcloud-net

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - /certs/nextcloud.crt:/etc/nginx/certs/nginx.crt
      - /certs/nextcloud.key:/etc/nginx/certs/nginx.key
      - /nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - nextcloud-net

networks:
  nextcloud-net:
    driver: bridge
```

And the nginx.conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 10.0.0.124;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name 10.0.0.124;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/nginx.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nextcloud;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

When I try to connect to http://10.0.124:8080, it load the Nextcloud page. but when I try to connect to https://10.0.0.124, nothing loads. Screenshot of the browser error:
[Screenshot of the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE6bG.png)

I tried

- many different configuration of the docker-compose.yml and nginx.conf file (eg. port 8080:443, 80:443, etc.)
- regenarating the self-signed certificate
- checking the firewall

I want the web access to work via https only. Not http.